# When inserting a Frame, the background image of my Tk() window is being partially covered

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, frame

I create a window in `Tk()` and add a background image. When I create a `frame`, it is covering part of the image. I already looked for some similar questions about get the frame transparent, but that is not that I want. I would like the frame to just show the buttons inside without affecting the background image.

Here is a modified code, to show you what is the problem:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master = None)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
        self.menu_option()
        self.image_font()
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("ATO Home Screem")
        self.master.geometry("600x400")
        self.master.configure(background = "#42f4f4")
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
    def menu_option(self):
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu = menu)
        filemenu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label = 'New')
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label = 'Open')
        filemenu.add_command(label = 'Save As')
        filemenu.add_command(label = 'Save')
        filemenu.add_separator() 
        filemenu.add_command(label = 'Exit')
    def image_font(self):
        image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\ATO.png")
        image = image.resize((600,400),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photoImg =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        panel = Label(self.master,image = photoImg) 
        panel.image = photoImg
        panel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
        panel.configure(image = photoImg)

master = Tk()
Window(master)
frame = Frame(master) 
frame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
Button(frame, text = "Test") .place(x = 50, y = 50)
master.mainloop()
```

I would like to know if you have any idea of how to solve it, or if you recommend me to use another kind of GUI tool.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You're creating a `Label` with an image on it whose `master` is the whole `tkinter` aoolications window (not the `frame` subclass  `Window` instance being created). To confuse matters even more, this is being done in a method named `image_font()`.

Comment: When I run the code, the frame is showed over the image. What I want is the image (background) not to be affected by the frame.

Comment: You have two `Frame` instances named `Window` and `frame` respectively, so you need to be clear about which one you're taking about.

Comment: *"show the buttons without affecting the background image"*: This is possible using `Canvas` instead of `Frame` and the `Canvas` methods `.create_image` and `.create_window`.

Comment: Thanks stovfl with Canvas is better to work